# Ruby: Time-based encrypted key?

Tags: ruby, encryption

I have a URL that tracks clicks and I want to prevent users from sharing that URL.

So, the idea I had was to create a unique URL that has a string that's some sort of encrypted timestamp (with a salt), and if the link was clicked within 5 minutes of that encrypted timestamp, then it would be valid.

Is there a better way to do this? If not, how would I decrypt it since the timestamp of when this was generated vs. when it was clicked would be different most of the time?

Comment: That should work, but it seem like you could simply pass out a random number and remember that number for 5 minutes.

Comment: If you are able to decrypt the URL and get the generation time, wouldn't it be trivial to compare it with click time and see if it is within five minutes?

Comment: @sawa I guess that's what I'm having trouble with. If I encrypt based on `1358999780 + MY_SALT`...how can I decrypt if the unix timestamp is totally different?

Comment: Why do you need a different salt each time? Can't you just have your secret salt as a constant and use it all the time?

Comment: Huh? I don't. The salt stays the same. The unix timestamp changes...which would change what the output string.

Comment: Huuuh? So you know the salt and why can't you decript the URL and get the generation time?

Comment: Maybe it's the way I've thought to encrypt...but my decryption is based on matching encryption strings. Encrypted strings with different timestamps wouldn't match.

Comment: Aren't you encripting the generation time stamp? That is passed as a URL, and is returned by the user click, which you can decript back to the generation time stamp, right?

Comment: I think @Shpigford is confusing encryption with hashing, which are very different (the former is two-way, the latter one-way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page is served, generate a timestamp convered to the time zone UTC. Encrypt it symmetrically (use AES-256 for example) and place it in the URL.

When a user asks to go to a URL with such an encrypted timestamp, decrypt it with the same key (EDIT: make the key a *salted* hash of the content in question, such that every differing content has a different, but always the same, key). If the timestamp is less than 5 minutes ago compared to the server's timestamp converted to the time zone UTC, reject it, else accept it.

The user can't trick you by entering a different encrypted timestamp, since they don't know and can't find out your key (even knowing what timestamp it would have been and the encryption algorithm does not give enough information to find out your key) and all the timestamp picking and comparing is done serverside.

EDIT: With the edit, they also can't take a timestamp valid for one piece of content and attach it to a timestamp valid for another piece of content.

Comment: If you don't have a significant security requirement then I think this approach fine otherwise it will be possible to break the encryption (eventually) if you are using a fixed salt.

Comment: I'm not following how I'd decrypt the string, though. When decrypting, I wouldn't know the original timestamp.

Comment: You encrypt the timestamp with key K and end up with an encrypted timestamp. At a later time you decrypt the timestamp with the same key K and you get the original timestamp back.

Comment: The key is based on the salted hash of the content, not on the original timestamp. So you extract the key from the content and get the timestamp back.

Comment: This seems overly complex. You still need to store the key. If you can "extract the key from the content", why can't the attacker do the same? Also, timestamps can't give nearly enough entropy to be used as a key, even with a salt. With millisecond resolution, it's only as strong as a 4 character password (assuming 6 bits of entropy  per character).

Comment: The key is the hash of the content with a constant salt, so you're storing one salt forever. You don't use the timestamp as the key, the timestamp is the thing being encrypted.

Comment: What is the content you refer to? I might not be reading things correctly, but I don't see any other data mentioned anywhere.

Comment: The content the URL references when you go to it. If there's no content the URL references, why go there?

Comment: That is full of flaws. Your basically leaking the key with every request. For many cases, whatever data is returned to me, I can probably figure out the data returned to you, especially if it's static or near static. URL's also have a lot of uses beyond just navigating to in a web browser, in this case it's for link tracking. Presumably it isn't returning content of any substantitive length, and neither PUT nor DELETE are required to return data.

Comment: I meant the content you get when you type in the URL, not what's in the URL, sorry. Anyway, let's say I take the content of the URL (which you do know) and do a keyed hash of the content using my constant salt (which you do not know). This is my key. I use this to encrypt the timestamp (which you can one of say 1000 values). What program will return the salt?

Comment: There are plenty of use cases where there is no content to return. You also have the problem of where are you going to securely store the salt? In the database? If that's the case, then why not just store some random token to begin with, and not deal with rendering content and all this complexity.

Comment: If there could be no content to return, then I concede that this solution is not going to work :)

Comment: There's also a problem if the content changes at all with each request. If the content included say, the current time, then you'd never get the same key.

Answer (score 3):

I think the comments and answers already given are overly complex. This problem seems analogous to password reset links. You could just:

1. Generate a random token and store a salted hash (or [PBKDF2(token, salt)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) for added security) of it in the database, along with the expiration time.
2. Whenever someone uses the URL, hash it and validate it against your stored copy, and make sure the time hasn't expired.

Any of the "encrypted timestamp" schemes still have the problem of how you securely deal with that AES key. Either you have a random key that you need to store, or it's derivable, in which case it's not secure.

Your threat model probably should assume that a compromise of the either the application or the database will lead to a compromise of the other. In which case, just store the token and don't add complexity.

If you still want to do embedded timestamps in the URL, you could look at the way [Azure Shared Access Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx) work, which includes a SHA256-HMAC in the URL.